# which design pattern allows me to implement two different classes, each class has a list of objects of the other class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class A and class B, class A has a list of instances of class B and class B has a list of instances of class A, in sql language, this is many to many relationship, is there a design pattern that helps in the implementation of these classes or am I overthinking it and it is just as simple as just assigning a respective list for each class?

Thanks

Comment: Since you mentioned M-M relationships in SQL, why not look up how an ORM represents a M-M relationship in code? For example, in [Hibernate (Java)](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many) or [Entity Framework (.NET)](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You are overthiking. I don't know why. But you sure are overthing.